# Error reading Parquet file from Azure Blob Storage using Apache Drill

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, apache-drill

I'm currently trying to read a Parquet file from Azure Blob Storage using Apache Drill.  I've added the .jar files for azure-storage-8.6.3.jar and hadoop-azure-3.2.1.jar.

I'm able to read a JSON file stored in Blob storage (see first screenshot below), however, when I try to read the Parquet file I get the following error:

ERROR [HY000] [MapR][Drill] (1040) Drill failed to execute the query: SELECT * FROM `az.default`.`./CLTYP/CLTYP_2020_04_29_09_57.parquet` LIMIT 100
[30038]Query execution error. Details:[ 
SYSTEM ERROR: StorageException: The requested operation is not allowed in the current state of the entity.
Please, refer to logs for more information.

I then downloaded the Parquet file to my laptop and was able to explore it without any issues (see second screenshot below).

I'm new to Drill and not sure how to proceed?  I'm not sure why the JSON reads work while the Parquet doesn't?  Spent some time searching for the specific error I'm seeing but without any luck.  Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running:  Apache Drill 1.17.0 on Windows 10 with MapR Drill ODBC Driver version: 1.3.22.1055

[Reading JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNV2R.png)

[Reading the Parquet file from disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajj95.png)

Comment: Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.